# Existence Sequence Forcing a.s Convergence to zero

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

My question is quite straightforward. I have a sequence $X_n$ of random variables. How can I find a sequence of constants $A_n$ such that $X_n/A_n \xrightarrow{\text{a.s}} 0$. This question is quite strange as all these variables very well could have $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = +\infty$ or they progressively grow faster and faster. My first idea was using the following:

$$Y_n \xrightarrow{\text{a.s}} 0 \Longleftrightarrow \forall \varepsilon > 0, \,\mathbb{P}(|Y_n| > \varepsilon \; \text{infinitely often}) = 0$$

But I don't know how the constants could be managed to make the above statement valid. So any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming each $X_{n}$ is a.s. finite (otherwise there may be no such constants),  we have

$$
  0
  = \mathbb{P}(|X_{n}| = \infty)
  = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_{n}| > k),
$$

so for each $n$ we can find $k_{n}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(|X_{n}| > k_{n}) < \frac{1}{2^{n}}$. Take $A_{n} = n k_{n}$. If $\varepsilon > 0$, then for any $n > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$, we have

$$
  \mathbb{P}\bigg(\frac{|X_{n}|}{A_{n}} > \varepsilon\bigg)
  \leq \mathbb{P}\bigg(\frac{|X_{n}|}{A_{n}} > \frac{1}{n}\bigg)
  < \frac{1}{2^{n}}.
$$

By [Borel-Cantelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma),

$$
  \mathbb{P}\bigg(\frac{|X_{n}|}{A_{n}} > \varepsilon \text{ infinitely often}\bigg)
  = 0,
$$

which combines with your idea to show $X_{n} / A_{n} \rightarrow 0$ a.s.

Comment: Lovely solution. Just a small question, we assumed $X_n$ a.s finite, because otherwise$ \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_{n}| > k)$ would be non-zero right?

Comment: @JohannMartens Yep, that's right.